# Text from dt-tag is not outputted?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

i try to get a text from a website using the following code:

```
import time
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

if __name__ == '__main__':
  os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0' 
  options = Options()
  # options.add_argument('--headless=new')  
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service()
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)        

  wLink = "https://www.medimops.de/agatha-christie-agatha-christie-ein-schritt-ins-leere-why-didn-t-they-ask-evans-der-komplette-vierteiler-mit-starbesetzung-blu-ray-blu-ray-M0B0BW28MKKR.html"
  driver.get (wLink)       
  time.sleep(3) 
  soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'lxml')      
  wTitle = soup.find("div", {"class": "detail-page__title"}).text.strip()
  worker = soup.find("dl", {"class": "product-attributes__table"})
  worker = worker.find("template")
  wDT = worker.find("dt")
  print(wDT)
  print(wDT.text)
  print(list(wDT.stripped_strings))
  driver.quit()
```

I get this as output for the print-statements:

```
<dt class="product-attributes__definition">EAN / ISBN-<!-- -->:</dt>

[]
```

Why is the text ("EAN / ISBN") from the dt-tag not outputted?

Comment: first check what you get in `driver.page_source`.You could use at least `print()` for check it Maybe server sends different HTML than you expect. Next you could check what you get with `find('div')` and later with `find('div', {"class": "detail-page__title"})`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is enough for you to get the text before the comment, then use access to child elements through `contents`.

```
print(wDT.text) ---- print(wDT.contents[0])
```

[Doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)

> If a tag has only one child, and that child is a NavigableString, the child is made available as .string:

Because of the comment `.string` and does not work.

Comment: Thx that worked - but i still not understand why i get no output using .stripped_string or .text and only with .contents

Comment: @Rapid1898 Added a link to the documentation in the answer.